# p:calendar and other comps below override behaviour

Tags: primefaces-mobile

I use PrimeFacesMobile 6.0 and when I have a p:calendar and below one or more other components like p:selectOneMenu/button/text, the mobile browser doesn't work with p:calendar days, it clicks the p:selectOneMenu that is below, it only works if the day is "lucky" and positioned in a region out of all the
other components in the page.

I tested the calendar from RichFaces, and it works fine. The problem is that RichFaces doesn't have mobile support like PrimeFaces.

I think there is some problem with the panel opened by calendar to show the days.

[page with p:calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCoMF.png)

[page showing all the components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qHbT.png)

Comment: It seems you have a CSS issue. Can you insert some code (like CSS, template, screen) or images in order to understand better what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi @X-spert I changed the original question to show the xhtml page.

Comment: You can try to put a z-index of "99999" on ".ui-datepicker" (you must have a position on ".ui-datepicker", other than "static"). Maybe it is about positioning.

Comment: @X-spert thanks I configured z-index in all the components of the page and p:calendar worked fine

Comment: Good. If that works for you maybe it's a solution and you can mark the question as resolved. Good Luck!